# Cannot run shell script in node environment (fish shell)

Tags: shell, fish

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/node                                                                                                                                                      

 console.log('HELLO')
```

This file has been named `test`. No extension. If I try running it in my terminal like so

```
$ test
```

There is no output. However, if I run

```
/usr/bin/node test
```

I get the desired output:

```
HELLO
```

Why isn't my script giving the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type a command, and it's not an absolute or relative path (like ../test, or /bin/test, or ~/test), then the shell has to search for the executable. It does this by looking in the directories specified in $PATH. You can print it:

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

Notice that the current directory `.` is not in PATH. This is deliberate: if PATH contained `.`, then it's possible that a command may be accidentally or maliciously overridden by a file in the current directory.

You can ask which command you'd get:

```
> which test
/bin/test
```

That's what's being run, and why there's no output.

To run a command that's not in PATH, use an absolute or relative path:

```
./test
```

That should fix your problem.