# Minimal Bash script doesn't run properly without ./

Tags: bash

Illustrated in this console session

```
bir@N2C:~$ echo $PATH
.../home/bir/bin:...         # script folder is in PATH
bir@N2C:~$ ls -lh ~/bin/     # script permissions look ok
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bir bir   28 Jul 31 21:46 test
...
bir@N2C:~$ test              # no output
bir@N2C:~$ ~/bin/test
startend                     # anticipated output
bir@N2C:~$ cd ~/bin/
bir@N2C:~/bin$ ./test
startend                     # anticipated output
bir@N2C:~/bin$  cat test     
#!/bin/sh
echo "start$1end"
```

Also:

```
bir@N2C:~$ which test
/home/bir/bin/test
bir@N2C:~$ whereis test
test: /usr/bin/test /usr/bin/X11/test /usr/share/man/man1/test.1.gz
```

(And I have to add something here because my post is mostly code.)

Comment: Can you show the whole `$PATH` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run shell script in node environment (fish shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030324/cannot-run-shell-script-in-node-environment-fish-shell)

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a test in /usr/bin/test, which would be ahead of the one in your home directory in your path.  You can figure this out by entering the command `which test`

EDIT: As Alok Singhal points out in a comment below, `test` is also one of the commands built into the bash shell (and some other shells), and if you are using bash, then *another* built-in shell command, `type`, can show you, not only which `test` will be executed (even if it is a shell built-in and not available on the file system), but also, all the versions of test it is hiding.  For example, if I have /home/pat/bin ahead of /usr/bin:

```
$ type -a test
test is a shell builtin
test is /home/pat/bin/test
test is /usr/bin/test
```

So, typing `type -a <cmdname>` is very useful to figure out, not only what will be executed, but also what will *not* be executed.  By showing full paths, it also lets you use cut and paste (in most terminal programs) to choose and execute the proper program, even if you decide not to rename it.  (Other shells also have similar alias facilities.)

As an aside, `man type` won't give you any useful information about the `type` bash shell command, because it's not a standalone program.  `man bash` does describe it, since it is built in to the bash shell -- but there are a lot of uses of the literal word "type" in that document, so it's quickest to scroll to the bottom if you are looking for information on the `type` command.

EDIT2: As hek2mgl points out, the hash command also be useful if you are having trouble getting your command to execute.  In particular, if you have created a program that has the same name as something else, and you have already run that something else, your script may not run, even though it's first in the path:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
$ echo echo Hi there! > bin/python
$ chmod 700 bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
$ hash -r  # Clear the hash for this instance of bash
$ python
Hi there!
$ rm bin/python 
$ python
bash: /home/pat/bin/python: No such file or directory
$ hash -r
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: I've added the `hash -d test`, but I'm not sure anymore because test is a builtin.

Comment: Also, `test` is a shell builtin in `bash` (`type -a test`), so even if `~/bin` was the first entry, it might not work.  It's usually a bad idea to name a test program `test` in Unix, unfortunately!

Comment: @AlokSinghal Indeed, wanted to mention this just in this moment! :)

Comment: I just duplicated the problem.  Don't name your script "test" and it should work fine.  Don't name it "ls" either.  :-)

Comment: Good points on the bash built-ins and the use of `type`.  I guess I automatically shy away from built-ins so `which` works fine for me in most cases...

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Just add the builtin information to your answer. I needed to remove my up-vote because the builtin information is indeed inportant and missing here... would re-upvote then! :)

Comment: Indeed `which` doesn't indicate a problem... I had no inkling there was a `test` builtin. Thanks folks!